Growth Order of the Weierstrass Sigma Function $\sigma(z)$
This is Exercise 5 of Chapter 9 from Stein & Shakarchi's Complex Analysis:

Let $\sigma(z)$ be the canonical product
$$\sigma(z)=z\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}E_2\left(\tfrac{z}{\tau_j}\right)$$
where $\tau_j$ is an enumeration of the periods $\{n+m\tau\}$ with $(n,m)\neq(0,0)$, and $E_2(z)=(1-z)e^{z+\frac{z^2}{2}}$. Show that $\sigma(z)$ is an entire function of order $2$ that has simple zeros at all the periods $n+m\tau$, and vanishes nowhere else.

My attempt: Denote the lattice by $\Lambda$. Given $z$, the set of $\omega\in\Lambda$ for which $|\omega|<2|z|$ is finite. If $\omega$ is not in that set, we have
\begin{align*}
    \left|\log E_2\left(\tfrac{z}{\omega}\right)\right|&=\left|\log\left(1-\frac{z}{\omega}\right)+\frac{z}{\omega}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)^2\right|=\left|\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)^3+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)^4+\cdots\right|\\
    &\leq\frac{1}{3}\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^3\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots\right)<\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^3.
   \end{align*}
So the infinite product converges absolutely and uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. Accordingly, it defines an entire function and it is clear that its zeros are at the points of $\Lambda$ and are simple.
I know the above results can be deduced in another way using Weierstrass or Hadamard's theorems in infinite products (see Chapter 5 of this textbook), but it seems they can only tell the growth order of $\sigma(z)$ as an entire function lies in $[2,3)$. Can anyone help me find the exact growth order?

Just a small modification to what you tried will work.
For $\omega\in\Lambda$ with $|\omega|\geq2|z|$ and any $\varepsilon\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ we have
\begin{align*}
    \left|\log E_2\left(\tfrac{z}{\omega}\right)\right|&=\left|\log\left(1-\frac{z}{\omega}\right)+\frac{z}{\omega}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)^2\right|=\left|\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)^3+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{z}{\omega}\right)^4+\cdots\right|\\
    &\leq\frac{1}{3}\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^{2+\varepsilon}\left(\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^{1-\varepsilon}+\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^{2-\varepsilon}+\cdots\right)\leq\frac{1}{3}\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^{2+\varepsilon}\left(\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^{\frac{3}{2}}+\cdots\right)\\
    &\leq\frac{1}{3}\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^{2+\varepsilon}\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+\cdots\right]=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\left|\frac{z}{\omega}\right|^{2+\varepsilon}.
   \end{align*}
Since the series
$$\sum_{(n,m)\neq(0,0)}\frac{1}{|n+m\tau|^{r}}$$
converges whenever $r>2$, we conclude that $\sigma(z)$ is of order $2$.
